# SQL 2005: Maximum number of columns per table?

Tags: sql-server-2005, database

In MS SQL 2005, how many columns can you create in a table before hitting the limit?

I think it is 1024 columns per table but I'm not 100% sure. Just need a confirmation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=SQL.90).aspx) it appears that you are correct.  However, hitting that limit would seem strange.